# How to create a `BarChart[]` with color rules determined from categorical data?

Tags: graphics, color, histograms, charts

Let's say I have a list of color names (strings), like this:

```
samples = {{"blue, red, red"}, {"purple, blue, purple"}, {"blue, blue"}};
```

Then I can plot the frequency of the words (I remove spaces and split by commas in this case).

```
data = Flatten[
   StringDelete[#, " "] & /@ (StringSplit[#, ","] & /@ 
      Flatten[samples])];
chart = BarChart[Counts[data]/Length[data], ChartLabels -> Automatic, 
  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

How could I detect the 'categories' and make an appropiate color accordingly?

I look for something like `ColorRules -> {"blue" -> Blue, "red" -> Red, "purple" -> Purple}` to make the color of each bar corresponding to the color category I'm showing here (I use strings representing colors as an example, in a general application, it can be anything, like `{"birds"->Blue, "horses"->Red}`, etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a copy of your input.

```
samples = {{"blue, red, red"}, {"purple, blue, purple"}, \
{"blue, blue"}}
(* {{"blue, red, red"}, {"purple, blue, purple"}, {"blue, blue"}} *)

data = 
 Flatten[StringDelete[#, " "] & /@ (StringSplit[#, ","] & /@ 
     Flatten[samples])]
(* {"blue", "red", "red", "purple", "blue", "purple", "blue", \
"blue"} *)
```

I will add an intermediary variable that is not required. Just added to make it easier to follow.

```
dataCount = Counts[data]/Length[data]
(* <|"blue" -> 1/2, "red" -> 1/4, "purple" -> 1/4|> *)
```

Use `Keys` to extract the keys from the association

```
keys = Keys[dataCount]
(* {"blue", "red", "purple"} *)
```

Now you can use regular replacement to convert this to a list of colors.

```
keys /. {"blue" -> Blue, "red" -> Red, "purple" -> Purple}
(* {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5]} *)
```

Use this list as the `ChartStyle` for the `BarChart`.

```
BarChart[dataCount,
 ChartLabels -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True,
 ChartStyle -> Keys[dataCount] /. {"blue" -> Blue, "red" -> Red, 
   "purple" -> Purple}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
samples = {{"blue, red, red"}, {"purple, blue, purple"}, {"blue, blue"}};

tally = Tally[Flatten[TextWords /@ samples]];
{keys, counts} = Transpose @ tally;
counts = Normalize[counts, Total];
colors = {Blue, Red, Purple};
coloring = AssociationThread[keys, colors];

bcdata = Labeled[Style[#2, coloring @ #], #] & @@@ tally;
BarChart[bcdata]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
bcdata2 = Labeled[#2 -> coloring @ #, #] & @@@ tally;
BarChart[bcdata2]
```

> same picture

Also

```
BarChart[counts, ChartStyle -> (coloring/@keys), ChartLabels -> keys]
```

> same picture